# OnTouchListener on invisible view

Tags: android, animation, view, listener, invisible

so all I want to do is to touch on a certain part of the screen where an invisible view is hidden.

After that touch the view should fade In.
The Problem: The Listener isn't triggered whe I touch the view.

Things I've tried: view.setImageAlpha(0), view.setAlpha(0), view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
When I set alpha=1 the listener works fine.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Thanks to @Viswanath L for the great solution which he mentioned in his post as second workaround.

I just wanted to give a little code example for that in case someone doesn't know how this works:

What I want: I want to touch the right corner of the screen and at this spot, a view(myView) should fade in.

```
   fadeInListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("TRIGGERED");
//The screen size here is 1080x1920(vertical)
                if (event.getRawX() > 800 && event.getRawY() > 1640) {
                     final AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
                     fadeIn.setDuration(500);
                     fadeIn.setFillAfter(true);
                     myView.startAnimation(fadeIn);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layout.setOnTouchListener(fadeInListener);
}
```

The layout is:

```
this.layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

And myView should be placed in the right corner and what's very important:

```
myView.setVisibility(View.Gone);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you keep it visible but change background colors, font colors, etc...to match the background so that it can't be seen?

Comment: Not really.
What I can do is placing a view with the bg color on it and let this view fade out, so it looks like my original 'hidden' view fades in. That would be my workaround but if there's any cleaner way with something like a special visibility or alpha option to make this work, that'd be great.

Comment: android:alpha=0 works fine with listener.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`INVISBLE` means you are trying to add a listener to a view which is not there. You can add the listener to a visible view only.

**WORKAROUND**

> 1) Try to make a dummy view which is visible but having the same color as background.
>
> 2) Try to set the listener for parent and check the position (whether the position does 
>      belongs to INVISIBLE view).

Comment: 1) Yes, I also had this workaround in mind. Wanted to know if there's a better solution though.
2) Hmm..interesting idea. I'll try that, thx!

Comment: Yup, the second solution works great, thanks! I edited my first post with a code example.

Answer (score 1):

`onTouchListener` does not trigger for an invisible `View`. You can make 2 exactly the same views one under another the one below having the map. It will be visible and so it can be touched but it will be obscured by the view above like they do here: http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your xml:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/my_inv_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        />

<View
        android:id="@+id/my_touch_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
```

And set up the click listener like this:

```
final View mTouchView = findViewById(R.id.my_touch_view);
final View mInvView = findViewById(R.id.my_inv_view);
mInvView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mTouchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mInvView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
});
```

Comment: He want to touch the same view which is invisible to make it visible. Not another view.

Comment: You cannot touch an invisible view. This is the "trick": you create a view that has the exact dimmensions and position to your invisible view, you make sure it is on top of your invisible view, so the click listener would work, and then you use that view for click listener, that "mask view", if you will, just as if you'd use the original one.

Comment: As long as it's working, it doesn't matter what the user is actually clicking on. Ignorance is bliss :)

Comment: Viswanath L Yes, if that'd work that'd be great! But it seems that invisible views arent touchable.
@DDsix thank you. I also had this workaround in mind but I wanted to know if there's a better solution or at least if an invisble view is touchable. So thanks for that!